# Exeption on massAction delete

Tags: magento2, grid, delete, massaction

It's my massAction controller:

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: pkushnerevich
 * Date: 19.10.18
 * Time: 18.20
 */

namespace Aty\TestTask\Controller\Adminhtml\AddedList;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class MassDelete extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    protected $filter;

    protected $collectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Ui\Component\MassAction\Filter $filter,
        \Aty\TestTask\Model\ResourceModel\InsSku\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory)
    {
        $this->filter = $filter;
        $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $collection = $this->filter->getCollection($this->collectionFactory->create())->walk('delete');
        $collectionSize = $collection->getSize();

        $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('A total of %1 element(s) have been deleted.', $collectionSize));

        $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
        return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
    }
}
```

Exception: Some transactions have not been committed or rolled back

After debugger I found, that it's here

vendor/magento/framework/Model/AbstractModel.php

```
 public function beforeDelete()
    {
        if (!$this->_actionValidator->isAllowed($this)) {
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                new \Magento\Framework\Phrase('Delete operation is forbidden for current area')
            );
        }

        $this->_eventManager->dispatch('model_delete_before', ['object' => $this]);
        $this->_eventManager->dispatch($this->_eventPrefix . '_delete_before', $this->_getEventData());
        $this->cleanModelCache();
        return $this;
    }
```

Comment: are you sure you getting proper collection data in variable `$collection` after line `$collection = $this->filter->getCollection($this->collectionFactory->create())->walk('delete');` ?

Comment: @Shashank Kumrawat , no but it must, I think, delete getted element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to do code like this.

```
namespace Aty\TestTask\Controller\Adminhtml\AddedList;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Amasty\TestTask\Model\ResourceModel\InsSkuFactory;

class MassDelete extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    protected $filter;

    protected $collectionFactory;
    protected $InsSkuFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Ui\Component\MassAction\Filter $filter,
        \Amasty\TestTask\Model\ResourceModel\InsSku\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        InsSkuFactory $InsSkuFactory)
    {
        $this->filter = $filter;
        $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
        $this->InsSkuFactory = $InsSkuFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $collection = $this->filter->getCollection($this->collectionFactory->create());
        $collectionSize = $collection->getSize();

        foreach ($collection as $item) 
        {
            $model = $this->InsSkuFactory->create();
            $model->load($item->getId());
            $model->delete();
        }

        $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('A total of %1 element(s) have been deleted.', $collectionSize));

        $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
        return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
    }
}
```

Comment: it's doesn't work( the same error

Comment: now you need to first confirm that, you are getting proper result into collection.

Comment: Argument 1 passed to Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb::load() must be an instance of Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel, string given, called in app/code/Aty/TestTask/Controller/Adminhtml/AddedList/MassDelete.php on line 45

Comment: load doesn't work

Comment: Is InsSkuFactory model  or ResourceModel?

Comment: That need to your model path, I just try to write the code from your example code.
Need to replace the proper model path with this, so the record is loaded and you need to remove that.

Comment: @Pasha do you getting answer of still face issue?